# Stream static video file through webrtc

Tags: webrtc, html5-video, html5-audio, web-audio-api, mediasoup

what I am trying to accomplish is to have on my page audio and video file. And then send them through webrtc. I managed to do this with audio using web audio api like this.
HTML:

```
  <audio id="audio">
    <source src="../assets/outfoxing.mp3" />
  </audio>
```

JS:

```
const audioElement = document.getElementById("audio");
const incomingSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);

const outgoingStream = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
incomingSource.connect(outgoingStream);
const outgoingTrack = outgoingStream.stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
audioElement.play();
await this.sendTransport.produce({ track: outgoingTrack });
```

For webrtc I am using mediasoup

Now I want to do the same with the video. But there is no such thing like web video api so I am stuck. How can I accomplish this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some limitations, but you could refer to this [sample implementation](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/video-pc/).

It uses the [`captureStream()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/captureStream).

Comment: For my usage it works like charm, thanks